# Bootstrap 3 nav dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using navbar with a dropdown menu (Bootstrap 3)

1. I resize the browser window < 767px
2. I open the menu
3. I resize the browser window > 767px
4. I open the dropdown menu (inside navbar)

The issue: A scrollbar appears in the dropdown menu. (see picture below)

[image: See picture here]

My "nav" element is relative position.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default clearfix" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse">
        <ul class="main-menu user hidden-xs">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Could you add an example (jsfiddle)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.. this is a known bug in Bootstrap 3.0.2 --

(https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11243)

One workaround is to..

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/96924

Answer (score 2):

Skelly's answer helped.  Thank you.  But since I was seeing a scrollbar during the collapsing activity, I needed to fix it like this:

```
.navbar-collapse.in, .navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Bootstrap applies the "collapsing" class as the menu collapses, then "in" once the collapse is complete. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem.

see this:
http://bootply.com/97248

1. run it
2. resize (make it smaller) browser window until it become mobile layout
3. open dropdown menu (don't close/collapse it back)
4. resize (make it bigger) browser window until it become desktop layout
5. you'll see the dropdown menu got vertical scrollbar

it's because the parent (#test in my example) still got 'in' class from when it's still mobile layout.

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

is it bug or by bootstrap design? Anyone know where to fix this in bootstrap.js?

EDIT :  thx Skelly!
can't upvote/comment.