# BUG: Bootstrap Fixed Collapsible Navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am having a bit of trouble with my top fixed collapsible bootstrap navbar.

Whenever I click on a link of my navigation bar, a strange horizontal bar that looks like a horizontal scrollbar appears above the navbar and then disappears instantly.

I tried removing all my JS , CSS, and the rest of the page leaving only the navbar, and the bug is still there, so I assume it is something about the syntax of that navbar.

Below is the code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">My Web</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#topBanner" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#proyecto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Proyecto</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#masInfoContainer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Galer&iacute;a</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#planosContainer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Planos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#mapContainerContainer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Ubicaci&oacute;n</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contacto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Contacto</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li style="font-size:12px"><a>(0000) 4444-4444</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Also, bootstrap scrollspy is not working for me on this navbar. I guess it might be the same issue.

Thank you very much for your assistance

EDIT: I found that the problem is on making the navbar collapsible. If I remove the data attributes from the li elements, this problem is gone, but on mobile when I touch on some link the navbar doesnt collapse back.

Comment: This is your navbar: http://jsfiddle.net/zncxpLua/

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug in bootstrap, according to this post :

[Bootstrap 3 nav dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199308/bootstrap-3-nav-dropdown)

You have to add some CSS to fix it :

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This a demo page you need to modify as you needs..**[DEMO Page](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/ej74xxq2/)**

HTML part

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Application</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 <li><a href="#itemss-list">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#itemss-list">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#itemss-list">Home</a></li>


            </ul></div>
    </div></nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.

The solution was adding .in class to the data-target attribute of the li elements on the navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">My Web</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar.in"><a href="#topBanner">Home</a></li>
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar.in"><a href="#proyecto">Proyecto</a></li>
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar.in"><a href="#masInfoContainer">Galer&iacute;a</a></li>
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar.in"><a href="#planosContainer">Planos</a></li>
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar.in"><a href="#mapContainerContainer">Ubicaci&oacute;n</a></li>
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar.in"><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li style="font-size:12px"><a>(54+11) 4444-4444</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maxime Mettley's comment helped.  Thank you.  But since I was seeing a scrollbar during the collapsing activity, I needed to fix it like this:

```
.navbar-collapse.in, .navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Bootstrap applies the "collapsing" class as the menu collapses, then "in" once the collapse is complete. I hope this helps someone else.